# Android. Align views inside linear layout without push away from screen.

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating app with list of items which should look like as follows:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|TextView--View--View--View---------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------|

|-----------------------------------------------------|
|TextViewTextViewTextView--View--View--View-----------|
|-----------------------------------------------------|

|-----------------------------------------------------|
|TextViewTextViewTextViewTextView..--View--View--View-|
|-----------------------------------------------------|
```

But in my case in third row TextView push away three views:

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
|TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView--View--Vi|
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewSubject"
        android:text="SUBJECT"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


      <View
          android:background="#FF0000"
          android:layout_weight="0"
          android:layout_width="10dp"
          android:layout_height="10dp"/>
      <View
          android:layout_weight="0"
          android:background="#00FF00"
          android:layout_width="10dp"
          android:layout_height="10dp"/>
      <View
          android:layout_weight="0"
          android:background="#0000FF"
          android:layout_width="10dp"
          android:layout_height="10dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I tried use RelativeLayout, but in that way 3 views always align right parent. I want that 3 views follows textview and not been pushed away from screen.

Is that possible to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If space on device is not available, then how can they all fit in. If textviews covers say, 75% of screen, then how can views bigger than 25% fit in. And even you manage to fit on this screen size, but on smaller screen sizes, it might still spill over.

Comment: @AbhinavPuri yes. I understand this. I want these 3 views will be on screen always and left textview fit available space to left of these 3 views. If there not enough space then textview maybe invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="largeTextlargeTextlargeTextlargeTextlargeTextlargeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="95dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second linearLayout add `android:weightSum=4` and in each children View make `android:layout_weight=1` and make sure the `android:layout_width` is set to 0dp in child Views

Comment: In that case all views in layout will be with the same width. I need 3 views with fixed width (10dp).

Comment: If you want the text view to be for example 5 times bigger than the view you can set the weightSum to 8 and the textView weight to 5 and each view 1 but if you really want to 10dp exaclty use RelativeLayout and put the views aligned to right with 10dp fixed width and set the textView filling the left side -> aligned to left and set `android:layout_right="id of the view to the right"`. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

try using weight in linear layout

here,I have fixed it, you can change the weight to increase the size of button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="30"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewSubject"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="27"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="SUBJECT" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used your code. 3 views aligned to right side. I need align them to left side of textview.

Comment: you to align your views to the left of Textview.

Comment: If you want to align to left than place your views above the Textview, all the views then align to left side

Comment: I think we did not understand each other. I want to put first textview, then to right of this textview 3 views. And 3 views should be always on screen even textview is very long.

Answer (score 0):

try this, hope this is what you want. I just removed weight lines. Good luck

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewSubject"
            android:text="SUBJECT"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <View
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
        <View
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
        <View
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'm also trying to do this without weight, but this not working with long textview.

Comment: we already used ` android:singleLine="true" ` so our textview shouldn't be that long. but if you want to hinder this, you can limit your text length with ` android:maxLength="30" ` . so if you have a long text, it will show only 30 characters.